# Discord.py Bot - User info message

Tags: python, discord, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and currently, I want to add a feature when by use `_userinfo` command bot will send general information about the user (date when he joined Discord, date when he joined  this server, his nickname and his profile picture)

I have this code currently:

```py
if message.content.startswith("_userinfo"):
    emb14 = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{message.author.mention} info",
        colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
    )
    emb14.set_image(url=message.author.avatar_url)
    emb14.add_field(name=f"{message.author.mention}", value=f"{message.author}", inline=True)
    await message.channel.send(embed=emb14)
```

But then I have this message:
[image]

The problem is that the nickname is ID (but not `nickname#0000`) and that I don't know how to add server joining date and Discord joining date. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mention doesn't work properly with `discord Embed`, please check this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61747284/unable-to-tag-members-in-embed-messages-title-discord-py).

For getting the **server joining date** and **discord joining date**, you can use `created_at` and `joined_at` attributes on `user` respectively.

Please look through this below code,

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith("_userinfo"):
        emb14 = discord.Embed(
            title=f"@{message.author} info:",
            colour=discord.Colour.dark_blue()
        )
        emb14.set_image(url=message.author.avatar_url)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Name", value=f"{message.author}", inline=True)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Discord Joined date", value=f"{message.author.created_at}", inline=True)
        emb14.add_field(name=f"Server Joined date", value=f"{message.author.joined_at}", inline=True)
        await message.channel.send(embed=emb14)

client.run('YOUR TOKEN')
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thank you really much! It helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `{message.author.mention}` to `<@{message.author.id}>`. Also, note that mentioning in the title and footer doesn't work.